# C# - MOQ: How to add moq on this coding?

Tags: c#

I'm a total noob and new on moq.
I've got a very simple question to ask.

Given the code below, i would like to use moq to test if the return result is as expected.

```
  public class FrameworkServices : IFrameworkServices
   {    
    public ILoggingService getLogger()
    {
        return LoggingFactory.getInstance().Create(LoggingEnum.Log4Net);
    }
```

where ILogginService is an interface, LoogingFactory is a class.

Please share with me on how to moq this. All kind help are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a moq to check if a method returns as expected, just call the method and assert what you need, is a plain standard unit test. In the example you shown you can mock for example `IFrameworkService` and having getLogger returning a stub logger.